# Magento 2 Plugin After Execute Controller

Tags: magento2, after-plugin

Existing controller that returns a JSON.

```
public function execute()
{   

    $customer = $this->_customerModel->getById(175);
    $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
    $resultJson->setData(
        [
            'status' => 'ok',
            'message' => 'Success.',
            'data' => $customer->__toArray()
        ]
        );

    return $resultJson;
    
}
```

I have an afterExecute plugin where I try to get the data of the result

```
public function afterExecute(TestEndpoint $subject, $result)
{
    $result2 = json_decode($result);
    return $result;
}
```

There is an error saying thet $result is an Object not a JSON string. I want to get the customer data that was returned in the controller. How do I do that?

Comment: Plugins can not be used on Final methods,Final classes,Non-public methods,Class methods (such as static methods),__construct and __destruct,Virtual types,Objects that are instantiated before Magento\Framework\Interception is bootstrapped,Objects that implement Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\NoninterceptableInterface.
Read https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: are you looking for around plugin or after plugin? Because question title is different and descriptions is different.

Comment: Updated title to After

Comment: @VSalvador did you find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In afterExecute $result  is a json object if you want to get the data as an array you need to call getData() on $result to retrieve the data setted with setData()  in the original function.

Since the value of $result->getData() will be an array you cannot use json_decode but can use json_encode to get the value as a json string.

Comment: The $result is an object of type Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json,  it has setData() but no getData() even in the parent class